# Django - complex Query, matching 2+ alike fields in a model instance?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I was recently assigned a task for this week that has been giving me a tough time. given the Database model here...

```
class Company(models.Model):
    employee = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    primary_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
```

and the view here...

```
def check_company(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        company = request.GET.get('company')

        check_comp = Company.objects.filter(name=company.title()).count()

        if check_comp > 1:
            res = 'false'
        else:
            res = 'true'

        return HttpResponse(res)
```

right now, the `check_company` function checks whether the companies name is already in the database, and if it is, it alerts the user that the company is already in the database.

Now, I am trying to change this in a way that checks whether the company name, AND any OTHER field (website, primary_email, street, city) are already in the `Company` database together.

So, (name + website) or (name + primary_email), or (name + street) or (name + city)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to know which pair of fields failed the check or is that not important?

Comment: No, it just has to be name + one of the other field.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution you will get is using the unique together in meta tag

```
class Company(models.Model):
    employee = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    primary_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
           unique_together = ("name", "website","primary_email","street","city")
```

see how to implement from the django documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

EDIT:1

```
you can also provide list like this 
unique_together = [["name", "website"],
["name","primary_email",],
["name", "street"],
["name","city"]]
```

Comment: But would that make them ALL unique together? I just need name + one other field to return false. I don't need all 5 to be unique.

Comment: Definitely works, and creates one Company instance, Awesome!!

Now in a form, I am trying to find out a way to interrupt the user and say "Company is already registered"). Maybe django messages can handle that.

Comment: Is it possible to use unique_constraints, with conditions? Basically the requirements changed a little. Now, if ANY 2 fields (name, website, primary_email, zip_code) are alike in a database instance, I don't want to create a new instance. That will basically trigger a "company match".